# Hiding an HTML form option until any dropdown value is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've done a lot of searching as my JS is not up to par, but every result seems to show how to change visibility based on the value that is selected from a dropdown. I would like to hide the form option (label and textbox in this case) UNTIL ANY value is selected from a given dropdown. I am trying to filter visibility based on the "column" dropdown, that gets populated from the "table" element selection. I am trying to hide the label and input box for "lookup" until the "column" is selected.

I feel that I'm close, but not sure what the problem is.

My current attempt:

```js
function showDiv(divId, element) {
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value === "" ? 'table-row' : 'none';
}

var data = {
        "coh_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "type", "co_num", "est_num", "cust_num", "cust_seq", "contact", "phone", "cust_po", "order_date", "taken_by", "terms_code", "ship_code", "price", "weight", "qty_packages", "freight", "misc_charges", "prepaid_amt", "sales_tax", "stat", "cost", "close_date", "slsman", "eff_date", "exp_date", "whse", "sales_tax_2", "logifld", "edi_order", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "delterm", "use_exch_rate", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "frt_tax_code1", "frt_tax_code2", "msc_tax_code1", "msc_tax_code2", "disc", "pricecode", "ship_partial", "ship_early", "matl_cost_t", "lbr_cost_t", "fovhd_cost_t", "vovhd_cost_t", "out_cost_t", "end_user_type", "exch_rate", "fixed_rate", "orig_site", "lcr_num", "projected_date", "order_source", "convert_type", "aps_pull_up", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "charfld1", "charfld2", "charfld3", "decifld1", "decifld2", "decifld3", "datefld", "config_id", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "include_tax_in_price", "trans_nat_2", "export_type", "external_confirmation_ref", "is_external", "lead_id", "opp_id", "days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance", "days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance", "shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance", "shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance", "consignment", "discount_type", "disc_amount", "prospect_id", "demanding_site", "demanding_site_po_num", "shipment_approval_required", "surcharge", "surcharge_t", "config_doc_id"],
        "coitem_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "co_num", "co_line", "co_release", "item", "qty_ordered", "qty_ready", "qty_shipped", "qty_packed", "disc", "cost", "price", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "due_date", "ship_date", "reprice", "cust_item", "qty_invoiced", "qty_returned", "cgs_total", "feat_str", "stat", "cust_num", "cust_seq", "prg_bill_tot", "prg_bill_app", "release_date", "promise_date", "whse", "wks_basis", "wks_value", "comm_code", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "delterm", "unit_weight", "origin", "cons_num", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "export_value", "ec_code", "transport", "pick_date", "pricecode", "u_m", "qty_ordered_conv", "price_conv", "co_cust_num", "packed", "bol", "qty_rsvd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "cgs_total_matl", "cgs_total_lbr", "cgs_total_fovhd", "cgs_total_vovhd", "cgs_total_out", "cost_conv", "matl_cost_conv", "lbr_cost_conv", "fovhd_cost_conv", "vovhd_cost_conv", "out_cost_conv", "ship_site", "sync_reqd", "co_orig_site", "cust_po", "rma_num", "rma_line", "projected_date", "consolidate", "inv_freq", "summarize", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "config_id", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "rcpt_rqmt", "trans_nat_2", "suppl_qty_conv_factor", "print_kit_components", "due_date_day", "external_reservation_ref", "non_inv_acct", "non_inv_acct_unit1", "non_inv_acct_unit2", "non_inv_acct_unit3", "non_inv_acct_unit4", "days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance", "days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance", "shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance", "shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance", "priority", "invoice_hold", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "qty_picked", "fs_inc_num", "promotion_code", "external_shipment_line_id", "last_external_shipment_doc_id", "last_process_shipment_doc_id", "external_shipment_status"],
        "item_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "item", "description", "qty_allocjob", "u_m", "lead_time", "lot_size", "qty_used_ytd", "qty_mfg_ytd", "abc_code", "drawing_nbr", "product_code", "p_m_t_code", "cost_method", "lst_lot_size", "unit_cost", "lst_u_cost", "avg_u_cost", "job", "suffix", "stocked", "matl_type", "family_code", "low_level", "last_inv", "days_supply", "order_min", "order_mult", "plan_code", "mps_flag", "accept_req", "change_date", "revision", "phantom_flag", "plan_flag", "paper_time", "dock_time", "asm_setup", "asm_run", "asm_matl", "asm_tool", "asm_fixture", "asm_other", "asm_fixed", "asm_var", "asm_outside", "comp_setup", "comp_run", "comp_matl", "comp_tool", "comp_fixture", "comp_other", "comp_fixed", "comp_var", "comp_outside", "sub_matl", "shrink_fact", "alt_item", "unit_weight", "weight_units", "charfld4", "cur_u_cost", "feat_type", "var_lead", "feat_str", "next_config", "feat_templ", "backflush", "charfld1", "charfld2", "charfld3", "decifld1", "decifld2", "decifld3", "logifld", "datefld", "track_ecn", "u_ws_price", "comm_code", "origin", "unit_mat_cost", "unit_duty_cost", "unit_freight_cost", "unit_brokerage_cost", "cur_mat_cost", "cur_duty_cost", "cur_freight_cost", "cur_brokerage_cost", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "bflush_loc", "reservable", "shelf_life", "lot_prefix", "serial_prefix", "serial_length", "issue_by", "serial_tracked", "lot_tracked", "cost_type", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "cur_matl_cost", "cur_lbr_cost", "cur_fovhd_cost", "cur_vovhd_cost", "cur_out_cost", "avg_matl_cost", "avg_lbr_cost", "avg_fovhd_cost", "avg_vovhd_cost", "avg_out_cost", "prod_type", "rate_per_day", "mps_plan_fence", "pass_req", "lot_gen_exp", "supply_site", "prod_mix", "stat", "status_chg_user_code", "chg_date", "reason_code", "supply_whse", "due_period", "order_max", "mrp_part", "infinite_part", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "supply_tolerance_hrs", "exp_lead_time", "var_exp_lead", "buyer", "order_configurable", "job_configurable", "cfg_model", "co_post_config", "job_post_config", "auto_job", "auto_post", "setupgroup", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "mfg_supply_switching_active", "time_fence_rule", "time_fence_value", "earliest_planned_po_receipt", "use_reorder_point", "reorder_point", "fixed_order_qty", "unit_insurance_cost", "unit_loc_frt_cost", "cur_insurance_cost", "cur_loc_frt_cost", "tax_free_matl", "tax_free_days", "safety_stock_percent", "tariff_classification", "lowdate", "rcpt_rqmt", "active_for_data_integration", "rcvd_over_po_qty_tolerance", "rcvd_under_po_qty_tolerance", "include_in_net_change_planning", "kit", "print_kit_components", "safety_stock_rule", "show_in_drop_down_list", "controlled_by_external_ics", "inventory_ucl_tolerance", "inventory_lcl_tolerance", "separation_attribute", "batch_release_attribute1", "batch_release_attribute2", "batch_release_attribute3", "picture", "active_for_customer_portal", "featured", "top_seller", "overview", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "attr_group", "dimension_group", "lot_attr_group", "track_pieces", "bom_last_import_date", "save_current_rev_upon_bom_import", "nafta_pref_crit", "subject_to_nafta_rvc", "producer", "nafta_country_of_origin", "must_use_future_rcpts_before_pln", "portal_pricing_site", "portal_pricing_enabled", "subject_to_excise_tax", "excise_tax_percent", "freight_amt", "item_content", "estimated_matl_use_up_date", "last_matl_use_up_report_date", "PP_length_linear_dimension", "PP_width_linear_dimension", "PP_height_linear_dimension", "PP_linear_dimension_u_m", "PP_density", "PP_density_u_m", "PP_area", "PP_area_u_m", "PP_bulk_mass", "PP_bulk_mass_u_m", "PP_ream_mass", "PP_ream_mass_u_m", "PP_grade", "PP_abnormal_size", "PP_paper_mass_basis", "charge_item", "pull_up_safety_stock_rule", "pull_up_safety_stock_value", "commodity_jurisdiction", "eccn_usml_value", "export_compliance_program", "sched_b_num", "hts_code", "country", "fcst_bom_supply_flag"],
        "itemloc_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "whse", "item", "rank", "loc", "qty_on_hand", "mrb_flag", "loc_type", "inv_acct", "unit_cost", "perm_flag", "qty_rsvd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "lbr_acct", "fovhd_acct", "vovhd_acct", "out_acct", "wc", "inv_acct_unit1", "inv_acct_unit2", "inv_acct_unit3", "inv_acct_unit4", "lbr_acct_unit1", "lbr_acct_unit2", "lbr_acct_unit3", "lbr_acct_unit4", "fovhd_acct_unit1", "fovhd_acct_unit2", "fovhd_acct_unit3", "fovhd_acct_unit4", "vovhd_acct_unit1", "vovhd_acct_unit2", "vovhd_acct_unit3", "vovhd_acct_unit4", "out_acct_unit1", "out_acct_unit2", "out_acct_unit3", "out_acct_unit4", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "NewRank", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "last_count_qty_on_hand", "last_count_qty_rsvd", "qty_contained", "assigned_to_be_picked_qty", "inv_in_proc_acct", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit1", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit2", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit3", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit4", "lbr_in_proc_acct", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit1", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit2", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit3", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit4", "fovhd_in_proc_acct", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4", "vovhd_in_proc_acct", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4", "out_in_proc_acct", "out_in_proc_acct_unit1", "out_in_proc_acct_unit2", "out_in_proc_acct_unit3", "out_in_proc_acct_unit4", "count_sequence"],
        "job_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "type", "job", "suffix", "job_date", "cust_num", "ord_type", "ord_num", "ord_line", "ord_release", "est_job", "est_suf", "item", "qty_released", "qty_complete", "qty_scrapped", "stat", "lst_trx_date", "root_job", "root_suf", "ref_job", "ref_suf", "ref_oper", "ref_seq", "low_level", "effect_date", "wip_acct", "wip_total", "wip_complete", "wip_special", "revision", "picked", "whse", "jcb_acct", "ps_num", "wip_lbr_acct", "wip_fovhd_acct", "wip_vovhd_acct", "wip_out_acct", "wip_matl_total", "wip_lbr_total", "wip_fovhd_total", "wip_vovhd_total", "wip_out_total", "wip_matl_comp", "wip_lbr_comp", "wip_fovhd_comp", "wip_vovhd_comp", "wip_out_comp", "rollup_date", "wip_acct_unit1", "wip_acct_unit2", "wip_acct_unit3", "wip_acct_unit4", "jcb_acct_unit1", "jcb_acct_unit2", "jcb_acct_unit3", "jcb_acct_unit4", "wip_lbr_acct_unit1", "wip_lbr_acct_unit2", "wip_lbr_acct_unit3", "wip_lbr_acct_unit4", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit1", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit2", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit3", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit4", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit1", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit2", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit3", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit4", "wip_out_acct_unit1", "wip_out_acct_unit2", "wip_out_acct_unit3", "wip_out_acct_unit4", "prod_mix", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "config_id", "co_product_mix", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "scheduled", "rcpt_rqmt", "export_type", "contains_tax_free_matl", "midnight_of_job_sch_end_date", "midnight_of_job_sch_compdate", "rework", "unlinked_xref", "prospect_id", "is_external", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "config_doc_id", "MO_bom_alternate_id", "MO_bom_alternate_description", "MO_co_job", "MO_product_cycle", "MO_qty_per_cycle", "MO_job_description"],
        "jobmatl_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "job", "suffix", "oper_num", "sequence", "matl_type", "item", "matl_qty", "units", "cost", "qty_issued", "a_cost", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "po_unit_cost", "effect_date", "obs_date", "scrap_fact", "qty_var", "fixovhd_t", "varovhd_t", "feature", "probable", "opt_code", "inc_price", "description", "pick_date", "bom_seq", "matl_qty_conv", "u_m", "inc_price_conv", "cost_conv", "backflush", "bflush_loc", "fmatlovhd", "vmatlovhd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "a_matl_cost", "a_lbr_cost", "a_fovhd_cost", "a_vovhd_cost", "a_out_cost", "matl_cost_conv", "lbr_cost_conv", "fovhd_cost_conv", "vovhd_cost_conv", "out_cost_conv", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "alt_group", "alt_group_rank", "planned_alternate", "new_sequence", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "PP_matl_is_paper", "MO_formula_matl_weight_pct"],
        "jobroute_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "job", "suffix", "oper_num", "wc", "setup_hrs_t", "setup_cost_t", "complete", "setup_hrs_v", "wip_amt", "qty_scrapped", "qty_received", "qty_moved", "qty_complete", "effect_date", "obs_date", "bflush_type", "run_basis_lbr", "run_basis_mch", "fixovhd_t_lbr", "fixovhd_t_mch", "varovhd_t_lbr", "varovhd_t_mch", "run_hrs_t_lbr", "run_hrs_t_mch", "run_hrs_v_lbr", "run_hrs_v_mch", "run_cost_t_lbr", "cntrl_point", "setup_rate", "efficiency", "fovhd_rate_mch", "vovhd_rate_mch", "run_rate_lbr", "varovhd_rate", "fixovhd_rate", "wip_matl_amt", "wip_lbr_amt", "wip_fovhd_amt", "wip_vovhd_amt", "wip_out_amt", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "yield", "opm_consec_oper", "MO_shared", "MO_seconds_per_cycle", "MO_formula_matl_weight", "MO_formula_matl_weight_units"],
        "location_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "loc", "description", "loc_type", "mrb_flag", "wc", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow"],
        "poitem_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "po_num", "po_line", "po_release", "item", "stat", "qty_ordered", "qty_received", "qty_rejected", "qty_voucher", "qty_returned", "item_cost", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "due_date", "rcvd_date", "vend_item", "root_job", "root_suf", "plan_cost", "voucher_cost", "non_inv_acct", "drop_ship_no", "drop_seq", "ship_addr", "promise_date", "release_date", "whse", "item_type", "cost_type", "comm_code", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "unit_weight", "delterm", "origin", "cons_num", "unit_mat_cost", "unit_duty_cost", "unit_freight_cost", "unit_brokerage_cost", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "export_value", "ec_code", "transport", "req_num", "req_line", "u_m", "qty_ordered_conv", "item_cost_conv", "plan_cost_conv", "unit_mat_cost_conv", "unit_duty_cost_conv", "unit_freight_cost_conv", "unit_brokerage_cost_conv", "non_inv_acct_unit1", "non_inv_acct_unit2", "non_inv_acct_unit3", "non_inv_acct_unit4", "lc_override", "revision", "drawing_nbr", "po_vend_num", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "expedited", "rcpt_rqmt", "unit_insurance_cost", "unit_insurance_cost_conv", "unit_loc_frt_cost", "unit_loc_frt_cost_conv", "trans_nat_2", "suppl_qty_conv_factor", "unlinked_xref", "due_date_day", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "ipr_id", "ipr_seq", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "fa_num", "fa_class", "dept"]
 }

window.onload = function() {
  var tableSel = document.getElementById("table");
  var columnSel = document.getElementById("column");
  var lookupSel = document.getElementById("lookup");
  for (var x in data) {
    tableSel.options[tableSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  table.onchange = function() {
    columnSel.length = 1;
    var z = data[this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      columnSel.options[columnSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  display: table;
}

p {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
}

input {
  display: table-cell;
}

hideMe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="pageToVisit">
  <p>
    <label for="table">Choose a table:</label>
    <select name="table" id="table" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Table</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br><br>
  <p>
    <label for="column">Column to Filter:</label>
    <select name="column" id="column">
      <option value="" selected="">Please Select a Table First</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br><br>
  <p id="hideme">
    <label for="lookup">Lookup Value:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lookup" name="lookup" value="" onchange="showDiv('hideMe', this)">
  </p>
  <br><br>
</form>
```

TIA for any and all advice!
(edited to include data variable in js)

Comment: What is `data` in `for (var x in data)`? If it's an array, `x` will be the indexes, not values. If it's an object, `x` will be the keys, not values.

Comment: `hideMe` in the CSS should be `#hideMe`

Comment: The data is a dictionary that uses the "tables" as keys to lists of "columns" for that table. It works properly. I only included it to show how my dropdowns are being created, if it is even relevant.

Comment: Please add it to the snippet so it can run.

Comment: Added. I also tried the above code with the #hideMe value in css to no effect.

Comment: Another typo: `hideMe` should be `hideme`. But I don't understand how this is supposed to work. You hide the text input, but you call `showDiv()` after editing that  input. How can you edit it if it's not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the `id` of the paragraph containing the hidden input. It should be `id="hideMe"` to match the CSS and the call to `showDiv()`.

The call to `showDiv()` shouldn't be in the `onchange` of the hidden input, it should be in the previous dropdown.

The condition in `showDiv()` is backwards. It should show the element when the dropdown's value is *not* empty.

```js
function showDiv(divId, element) {
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value !== "" ? 'table-row' : 'none';
}

var data = {
        "coh_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "type", "co_num", "est_num", "cust_num", "cust_seq", "contact", "phone", "cust_po", "order_date", "taken_by", "terms_code", "ship_code", "price", "weight", "qty_packages", "freight", "misc_charges", "prepaid_amt", "sales_tax", "stat", "cost", "close_date", "slsman", "eff_date", "exp_date", "whse", "sales_tax_2", "logifld", "edi_order", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "delterm", "use_exch_rate", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "frt_tax_code1", "frt_tax_code2", "msc_tax_code1", "msc_tax_code2", "disc", "pricecode", "ship_partial", "ship_early", "matl_cost_t", "lbr_cost_t", "fovhd_cost_t", "vovhd_cost_t", "out_cost_t", "end_user_type", "exch_rate", "fixed_rate", "orig_site", "lcr_num", "projected_date", "order_source", "convert_type", "aps_pull_up", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "charfld1", "charfld2", "charfld3", "decifld1", "decifld2", "decifld3", "datefld", "config_id", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "include_tax_in_price", "trans_nat_2", "export_type", "external_confirmation_ref", "is_external", "lead_id", "opp_id", "days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance", "days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance", "shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance", "shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance", "consignment", "discount_type", "disc_amount", "prospect_id", "demanding_site", "demanding_site_po_num", "shipment_approval_required", "surcharge", "surcharge_t", "config_doc_id"],
        "coitem_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "co_num", "co_line", "co_release", "item", "qty_ordered", "qty_ready", "qty_shipped", "qty_packed", "disc", "cost", "price", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "due_date", "ship_date", "reprice", "cust_item", "qty_invoiced", "qty_returned", "cgs_total", "feat_str", "stat", "cust_num", "cust_seq", "prg_bill_tot", "prg_bill_app", "release_date", "promise_date", "whse", "wks_basis", "wks_value", "comm_code", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "delterm", "unit_weight", "origin", "cons_num", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "export_value", "ec_code", "transport", "pick_date", "pricecode", "u_m", "qty_ordered_conv", "price_conv", "co_cust_num", "packed", "bol", "qty_rsvd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "cgs_total_matl", "cgs_total_lbr", "cgs_total_fovhd", "cgs_total_vovhd", "cgs_total_out", "cost_conv", "matl_cost_conv", "lbr_cost_conv", "fovhd_cost_conv", "vovhd_cost_conv", "out_cost_conv", "ship_site", "sync_reqd", "co_orig_site", "cust_po", "rma_num", "rma_line", "projected_date", "consolidate", "inv_freq", "summarize", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "config_id", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "rcpt_rqmt", "trans_nat_2", "suppl_qty_conv_factor", "print_kit_components", "due_date_day", "external_reservation_ref", "non_inv_acct", "non_inv_acct_unit1", "non_inv_acct_unit2", "non_inv_acct_unit3", "non_inv_acct_unit4", "days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance", "days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance", "shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance", "shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance", "priority", "invoice_hold", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "qty_picked", "fs_inc_num", "promotion_code", "external_shipment_line_id", "last_external_shipment_doc_id", "last_process_shipment_doc_id", "external_shipment_status"],
        "item_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "item", "description", "qty_allocjob", "u_m", "lead_time", "lot_size", "qty_used_ytd", "qty_mfg_ytd", "abc_code", "drawing_nbr", "product_code", "p_m_t_code", "cost_method", "lst_lot_size", "unit_cost", "lst_u_cost", "avg_u_cost", "job", "suffix", "stocked", "matl_type", "family_code", "low_level", "last_inv", "days_supply", "order_min", "order_mult", "plan_code", "mps_flag", "accept_req", "change_date", "revision", "phantom_flag", "plan_flag", "paper_time", "dock_time", "asm_setup", "asm_run", "asm_matl", "asm_tool", "asm_fixture", "asm_other", "asm_fixed", "asm_var", "asm_outside", "comp_setup", "comp_run", "comp_matl", "comp_tool", "comp_fixture", "comp_other", "comp_fixed", "comp_var", "comp_outside", "sub_matl", "shrink_fact", "alt_item", "unit_weight", "weight_units", "charfld4", "cur_u_cost", "feat_type", "var_lead", "feat_str", "next_config", "feat_templ", "backflush", "charfld1", "charfld2", "charfld3", "decifld1", "decifld2", "decifld3", "logifld", "datefld", "track_ecn", "u_ws_price", "comm_code", "origin", "unit_mat_cost", "unit_duty_cost", "unit_freight_cost", "unit_brokerage_cost", "cur_mat_cost", "cur_duty_cost", "cur_freight_cost", "cur_brokerage_cost", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "bflush_loc", "reservable", "shelf_life", "lot_prefix", "serial_prefix", "serial_length", "issue_by", "serial_tracked", "lot_tracked", "cost_type", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "cur_matl_cost", "cur_lbr_cost", "cur_fovhd_cost", "cur_vovhd_cost", "cur_out_cost", "avg_matl_cost", "avg_lbr_cost", "avg_fovhd_cost", "avg_vovhd_cost", "avg_out_cost", "prod_type", "rate_per_day", "mps_plan_fence", "pass_req", "lot_gen_exp", "supply_site", "prod_mix", "stat", "status_chg_user_code", "chg_date", "reason_code", "supply_whse", "due_period", "order_max", "mrp_part", "infinite_part", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "supply_tolerance_hrs", "exp_lead_time", "var_exp_lead", "buyer", "order_configurable", "job_configurable", "cfg_model", "co_post_config", "job_post_config", "auto_job", "auto_post", "setupgroup", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "mfg_supply_switching_active", "time_fence_rule", "time_fence_value", "earliest_planned_po_receipt", "use_reorder_point", "reorder_point", "fixed_order_qty", "unit_insurance_cost", "unit_loc_frt_cost", "cur_insurance_cost", "cur_loc_frt_cost", "tax_free_matl", "tax_free_days", "safety_stock_percent", "tariff_classification", "lowdate", "rcpt_rqmt", "active_for_data_integration", "rcvd_over_po_qty_tolerance", "rcvd_under_po_qty_tolerance", "include_in_net_change_planning", "kit", "print_kit_components", "safety_stock_rule", "show_in_drop_down_list", "controlled_by_external_ics", "inventory_ucl_tolerance", "inventory_lcl_tolerance", "separation_attribute", "batch_release_attribute1", "batch_release_attribute2", "batch_release_attribute3", "picture", "active_for_customer_portal", "featured", "top_seller", "overview", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "attr_group", "dimension_group", "lot_attr_group", "track_pieces", "bom_last_import_date", "save_current_rev_upon_bom_import", "nafta_pref_crit", "subject_to_nafta_rvc", "producer", "nafta_country_of_origin", "must_use_future_rcpts_before_pln", "portal_pricing_site", "portal_pricing_enabled", "subject_to_excise_tax", "excise_tax_percent", "freight_amt", "item_content", "estimated_matl_use_up_date", "last_matl_use_up_report_date", "PP_length_linear_dimension", "PP_width_linear_dimension", "PP_height_linear_dimension", "PP_linear_dimension_u_m", "PP_density", "PP_density_u_m", "PP_area", "PP_area_u_m", "PP_bulk_mass", "PP_bulk_mass_u_m", "PP_ream_mass", "PP_ream_mass_u_m", "PP_grade", "PP_abnormal_size", "PP_paper_mass_basis", "charge_item", "pull_up_safety_stock_rule", "pull_up_safety_stock_value", "commodity_jurisdiction", "eccn_usml_value", "export_compliance_program", "sched_b_num", "hts_code", "country", "fcst_bom_supply_flag"],
        "itemloc_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "whse", "item", "rank", "loc", "qty_on_hand", "mrb_flag", "loc_type", "inv_acct", "unit_cost", "perm_flag", "qty_rsvd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "lbr_acct", "fovhd_acct", "vovhd_acct", "out_acct", "wc", "inv_acct_unit1", "inv_acct_unit2", "inv_acct_unit3", "inv_acct_unit4", "lbr_acct_unit1", "lbr_acct_unit2", "lbr_acct_unit3", "lbr_acct_unit4", "fovhd_acct_unit1", "fovhd_acct_unit2", "fovhd_acct_unit3", "fovhd_acct_unit4", "vovhd_acct_unit1", "vovhd_acct_unit2", "vovhd_acct_unit3", "vovhd_acct_unit4", "out_acct_unit1", "out_acct_unit2", "out_acct_unit3", "out_acct_unit4", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "NewRank", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "last_count_qty_on_hand", "last_count_qty_rsvd", "qty_contained", "assigned_to_be_picked_qty", "inv_in_proc_acct", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit1", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit2", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit3", "inv_in_proc_acct_unit4", "lbr_in_proc_acct", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit1", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit2", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit3", "lbr_in_proc_acct_unit4", "fovhd_in_proc_acct", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3", "fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4", "vovhd_in_proc_acct", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3", "vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4", "out_in_proc_acct", "out_in_proc_acct_unit1", "out_in_proc_acct_unit2", "out_in_proc_acct_unit3", "out_in_proc_acct_unit4", "count_sequence"],
        "job_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "type", "job", "suffix", "job_date", "cust_num", "ord_type", "ord_num", "ord_line", "ord_release", "est_job", "est_suf", "item", "qty_released", "qty_complete", "qty_scrapped", "stat", "lst_trx_date", "root_job", "root_suf", "ref_job", "ref_suf", "ref_oper", "ref_seq", "low_level", "effect_date", "wip_acct", "wip_total", "wip_complete", "wip_special", "revision", "picked", "whse", "jcb_acct", "ps_num", "wip_lbr_acct", "wip_fovhd_acct", "wip_vovhd_acct", "wip_out_acct", "wip_matl_total", "wip_lbr_total", "wip_fovhd_total", "wip_vovhd_total", "wip_out_total", "wip_matl_comp", "wip_lbr_comp", "wip_fovhd_comp", "wip_vovhd_comp", "wip_out_comp", "rollup_date", "wip_acct_unit1", "wip_acct_unit2", "wip_acct_unit3", "wip_acct_unit4", "jcb_acct_unit1", "jcb_acct_unit2", "jcb_acct_unit3", "jcb_acct_unit4", "wip_lbr_acct_unit1", "wip_lbr_acct_unit2", "wip_lbr_acct_unit3", "wip_lbr_acct_unit4", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit1", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit2", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit3", "wip_fovhd_acct_unit4", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit1", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit2", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit3", "wip_vovhd_acct_unit4", "wip_out_acct_unit1", "wip_out_acct_unit2", "wip_out_acct_unit3", "wip_out_acct_unit4", "prod_mix", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "config_id", "co_product_mix", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "scheduled", "rcpt_rqmt", "export_type", "contains_tax_free_matl", "midnight_of_job_sch_end_date", "midnight_of_job_sch_compdate", "rework", "unlinked_xref", "prospect_id", "is_external", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "config_doc_id", "MO_bom_alternate_id", "MO_bom_alternate_description", "MO_co_job", "MO_product_cycle", "MO_qty_per_cycle", "MO_job_description"],
        "jobmatl_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "job", "suffix", "oper_num", "sequence", "matl_type", "item", "matl_qty", "units", "cost", "qty_issued", "a_cost", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "po_unit_cost", "effect_date", "obs_date", "scrap_fact", "qty_var", "fixovhd_t", "varovhd_t", "feature", "probable", "opt_code", "inc_price", "description", "pick_date", "bom_seq", "matl_qty_conv", "u_m", "inc_price_conv", "cost_conv", "backflush", "bflush_loc", "fmatlovhd", "vmatlovhd", "matl_cost", "lbr_cost", "fovhd_cost", "vovhd_cost", "out_cost", "a_matl_cost", "a_lbr_cost", "a_fovhd_cost", "a_vovhd_cost", "a_out_cost", "matl_cost_conv", "lbr_cost_conv", "fovhd_cost_conv", "vovhd_cost_conv", "out_cost_conv", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "alt_group", "alt_group_rank", "planned_alternate", "new_sequence", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "PP_matl_is_paper", "MO_formula_matl_weight_pct"],
        "jobroute_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "job", "suffix", "oper_num", "wc", "setup_hrs_t", "setup_cost_t", "complete", "setup_hrs_v", "wip_amt", "qty_scrapped", "qty_received", "qty_moved", "qty_complete", "effect_date", "obs_date", "bflush_type", "run_basis_lbr", "run_basis_mch", "fixovhd_t_lbr", "fixovhd_t_mch", "varovhd_t_lbr", "varovhd_t_mch", "run_hrs_t_lbr", "run_hrs_t_mch", "run_hrs_v_lbr", "run_hrs_v_mch", "run_cost_t_lbr", "cntrl_point", "setup_rate", "efficiency", "fovhd_rate_mch", "vovhd_rate_mch", "run_rate_lbr", "varovhd_rate", "fixovhd_rate", "wip_matl_amt", "wip_lbr_amt", "wip_fovhd_amt", "wip_vovhd_amt", "wip_out_amt", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "yield", "opm_consec_oper", "MO_shared", "MO_seconds_per_cycle", "MO_formula_matl_weight", "MO_formula_matl_weight_units"],
        "location_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "loc", "description", "loc_type", "mrb_flag", "wc", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow"],
        "poitem_mst": ["AUDIT_ID", "AUDIT_TimeStamp", "AUDIT_UID", "AUDIT_RecType", "AUDIT_TransId", "site_ref", "po_num", "po_line", "po_release", "item", "stat", "qty_ordered", "qty_received", "qty_rejected", "qty_voucher", "qty_returned", "item_cost", "ref_type", "ref_num", "ref_line_suf", "ref_release", "due_date", "rcvd_date", "vend_item", "root_job", "root_suf", "plan_cost", "voucher_cost", "non_inv_acct", "drop_ship_no", "drop_seq", "ship_addr", "promise_date", "release_date", "whse", "item_type", "cost_type", "comm_code", "trans_nat", "process_ind", "unit_weight", "delterm", "origin", "cons_num", "unit_mat_cost", "unit_duty_cost", "unit_freight_cost", "unit_brokerage_cost", "tax_code1", "tax_code2", "export_value", "ec_code", "transport", "req_num", "req_line", "u_m", "qty_ordered_conv", "item_cost_conv", "plan_cost_conv", "unit_mat_cost_conv", "unit_duty_cost_conv", "unit_freight_cost_conv", "unit_brokerage_cost_conv", "non_inv_acct_unit1", "non_inv_acct_unit2", "non_inv_acct_unit3", "non_inv_acct_unit4", "lc_override", "revision", "drawing_nbr", "po_vend_num", "NoteExistsFlag", "RecordDate", "RowPointer", "description", "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy", "CreateDate", "InWorkflow", "expedited", "rcpt_rqmt", "unit_insurance_cost", "unit_insurance_cost_conv", "unit_loc_frt_cost", "unit_loc_frt_cost_conv", "trans_nat_2", "suppl_qty_conv_factor", "unlinked_xref", "due_date_day", "preassign_lots", "preassign_serials", "ipr_id", "ipr_seq", "manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_item", "fa_num", "fa_class", "dept"]
 }

window.onload = function() {
  var tableSel = document.getElementById("table");
  var columnSel = document.getElementById("column");
  var lookupSel = document.getElementById("lookup");
  for (var x in data) {
    tableSel.options[tableSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  table.onchange = function() {
    columnSel.length = 1;
    var z = data[this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      columnSel.options[columnSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  display: table;
}

p {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
}

input {
  display: table-cell;
}

#hideMe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="pageToVisit">
  <p>
    <label for="table">Choose a table:</label>
    <select name="table" id="table" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select a Table</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br><br>
  <p>
    <label for="column">Column to Filter:</label>
    <select name="column" id="column" onchange="showDiv('hideMe', this)">
      <option value="" selected="">Please Select a Table First</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br><br>
  <p id="hideMe">
    <label for="lookup">Lookup Value:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lookup" name="lookup" value="">
  </p>
  <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! With my inexperience, It would have taken me awhile to spot all the issues. I have marked your solution as the answer.

Comment: The default `<option>` should be marked as `disabled`.

Comment: @InSync I'm not sure about that. `showDiv()` expects to be able to hide the div if you select the empty option.

Comment: On re-selecting the default, your snippet throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`. Also, default/placeholder option should be marked as `disabled`, since they are not supposed to be submitted.

Comment: There's no error for the second dropdown, I've added that for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that... if it's would be useful..

```js
const data = 
  { coh_mst      : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'type', 'co_num', 'est_num', 'cust_num', 'cust_seq', 'contact', 'phone', 'cust_po', 'order_date', 'taken_by', 'terms_code', 'ship_code', 'price', 'weight', 'qty_packages', 'freight', 'misc_charges', 'prepaid_amt', 'sales_tax', 'stat', 'cost', 'close_date', 'slsman', 'eff_date', 'exp_date', 'whse', 'sales_tax_2', 'logifld', 'edi_order', 'trans_nat', 'process_ind', 'delterm', 'use_exch_rate', 'tax_code1', 'tax_code2', 'frt_tax_code1', 'frt_tax_code2', 'msc_tax_code1', 'msc_tax_code2', 'disc', 'pricecode', 'ship_partial', 'ship_early', 'matl_cost_t', 'lbr_cost_t', 'fovhd_cost_t', 'vovhd_cost_t', 'out_cost_t', 'end_user_type', 'exch_rate', 'fixed_rate', 'orig_site', 'lcr_num', 'projected_date', 'order_source', 'convert_type', 'aps_pull_up', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'charfld1', 'charfld2', 'charfld3', 'decifld1', 'decifld2', 'decifld3', 'datefld', 'config_id', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'include_tax_in_price', 'trans_nat_2', 'export_type', 'external_confirmation_ref', 'is_external', 'lead_id', 'opp_id', 'days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance', 'days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance', 'shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance', 'shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance', 'consignment', 'discount_type', 'disc_amount', 'prospect_id', 'demanding_site', 'demanding_site_po_num', 'shipment_approval_required', 'surcharge', 'surcharge_t', 'config_doc_id']
  , coitem_mst   : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'co_num', 'co_line', 'co_release', 'item', 'qty_ordered', 'qty_ready', 'qty_shipped', 'qty_packed', 'disc', 'cost', 'price', 'ref_type', 'ref_num', 'ref_line_suf', 'ref_release', 'due_date', 'ship_date', 'reprice', 'cust_item', 'qty_invoiced', 'qty_returned', 'cgs_total', 'feat_str', 'stat', 'cust_num', 'cust_seq', 'prg_bill_tot', 'prg_bill_app', 'release_date', 'promise_date', 'whse', 'wks_basis', 'wks_value', 'comm_code', 'trans_nat', 'process_ind', 'delterm', 'unit_weight', 'origin', 'cons_num', 'tax_code1', 'tax_code2', 'export_value', 'ec_code', 'transport', 'pick_date', 'pricecode', 'u_m', 'qty_ordered_conv', 'price_conv', 'co_cust_num', 'packed', 'bol', 'qty_rsvd', 'matl_cost', 'lbr_cost', 'fovhd_cost', 'vovhd_cost', 'out_cost', 'cgs_total_matl', 'cgs_total_lbr', 'cgs_total_fovhd', 'cgs_total_vovhd', 'cgs_total_out', 'cost_conv', 'matl_cost_conv', 'lbr_cost_conv', 'fovhd_cost_conv', 'vovhd_cost_conv', 'out_cost_conv', 'ship_site', 'sync_reqd', 'co_orig_site', 'cust_po', 'rma_num', 'rma_line', 'projected_date', 'consolidate', 'inv_freq', 'summarize', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'description', 'config_id', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'rcpt_rqmt', 'trans_nat_2', 'suppl_qty_conv_factor', 'print_kit_components', 'due_date_day', 'external_reservation_ref', 'non_inv_acct', 'non_inv_acct_unit1', 'non_inv_acct_unit2', 'non_inv_acct_unit3', 'non_inv_acct_unit4', 'days_shipped_before_due_date_tolerance', 'days_shipped_after_due_date_tolerance', 'shipped_over_ordered_qty_tolerance', 'shipped_under_ordered_qty_tolerance', 'priority', 'invoice_hold', 'manufacturer_id', 'manufacturer_item', 'qty_picked', 'fs_inc_num', 'promotion_code', 'external_shipment_line_id', 'last_external_shipment_doc_id', 'last_process_shipment_doc_id', 'external_shipment_status']
  , item_mst     : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'item', 'description', 'qty_allocjob', 'u_m', 'lead_time', 'lot_size', 'qty_used_ytd', 'qty_mfg_ytd', 'abc_code', 'drawing_nbr', 'product_code', 'p_m_t_code', 'cost_method', 'lst_lot_size', 'unit_cost', 'lst_u_cost', 'avg_u_cost', 'job', 'suffix', 'stocked', 'matl_type', 'family_code', 'low_level', 'last_inv', 'days_supply', 'order_min', 'order_mult', 'plan_code', 'mps_flag', 'accept_req', 'change_date', 'revision', 'phantom_flag', 'plan_flag', 'paper_time', 'dock_time', 'asm_setup', 'asm_run', 'asm_matl', 'asm_tool', 'asm_fixture', 'asm_other', 'asm_fixed', 'asm_var', 'asm_outside', 'comp_setup', 'comp_run', 'comp_matl', 'comp_tool', 'comp_fixture', 'comp_other', 'comp_fixed', 'comp_var', 'comp_outside', 'sub_matl', 'shrink_fact', 'alt_item', 'unit_weight', 'weight_units', 'charfld4', 'cur_u_cost', 'feat_type', 'var_lead', 'feat_str', 'next_config', 'feat_templ', 'backflush', 'charfld1', 'charfld2', 'charfld3', 'decifld1', 'decifld2', 'decifld3', 'logifld', 'datefld', 'track_ecn', 'u_ws_price', 'comm_code', 'origin', 'unit_mat_cost', 'unit_duty_cost', 'unit_freight_cost', 'unit_brokerage_cost', 'cur_mat_cost', 'cur_duty_cost', 'cur_freight_cost', 'cur_brokerage_cost', 'tax_code1', 'tax_code2', 'bflush_loc', 'reservable', 'shelf_life', 'lot_prefix', 'serial_prefix', 'serial_length', 'issue_by', 'serial_tracked', 'lot_tracked', 'cost_type', 'matl_cost', 'lbr_cost', 'fovhd_cost', 'vovhd_cost', 'out_cost', 'cur_matl_cost', 'cur_lbr_cost', 'cur_fovhd_cost', 'cur_vovhd_cost', 'cur_out_cost', 'avg_matl_cost', 'avg_lbr_cost', 'avg_fovhd_cost', 'avg_vovhd_cost', 'avg_out_cost', 'prod_type', 'rate_per_day', 'mps_plan_fence', 'pass_req', 'lot_gen_exp', 'supply_site', 'prod_mix', 'stat', 'status_chg_user_code', 'chg_date', 'reason_code', 'supply_whse', 'due_period', 'order_max', 'mrp_part', 'infinite_part', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'supply_tolerance_hrs', 'exp_lead_time', 'var_exp_lead', 'buyer', 'order_configurable', 'job_configurable', 'cfg_model', 'co_post_config', 'job_post_config', 'auto_job', 'auto_post', 'setupgroup', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'mfg_supply_switching_active', 'time_fence_rule', 'time_fence_value', 'earliest_planned_po_receipt', 'use_reorder_point', 'reorder_point', 'fixed_order_qty', 'unit_insurance_cost', 'unit_loc_frt_cost', 'cur_insurance_cost', 'cur_loc_frt_cost', 'tax_free_matl', 'tax_free_days', 'safety_stock_percent', 'tariff_classification', 'lowdate', 'rcpt_rqmt', 'active_for_data_integration', 'rcvd_over_po_qty_tolerance', 'rcvd_under_po_qty_tolerance', 'include_in_net_change_planning', 'kit', 'print_kit_components', 'safety_stock_rule', 'show_in_drop_down_list', 'controlled_by_external_ics', 'inventory_ucl_tolerance', 'inventory_lcl_tolerance', 'separation_attribute', 'batch_release_attribute1', 'batch_release_attribute2', 'batch_release_attribute3', 'picture', 'active_for_customer_portal', 'featured', 'top_seller', 'overview', 'preassign_lots', 'preassign_serials', 'attr_group', 'dimension_group', 'lot_attr_group', 'track_pieces', 'bom_last_import_date', 'save_current_rev_upon_bom_import', 'nafta_pref_crit', 'subject_to_nafta_rvc', 'producer', 'nafta_country_of_origin', 'must_use_future_rcpts_before_pln', 'portal_pricing_site', 'portal_pricing_enabled', 'subject_to_excise_tax', 'excise_tax_percent', 'freight_amt', 'item_content', 'estimated_matl_use_up_date', 'last_matl_use_up_report_date', 'PP_length_linear_dimension', 'PP_width_linear_dimension', 'PP_height_linear_dimension', 'PP_linear_dimension_u_m', 'PP_density', 'PP_density_u_m', 'PP_area', 'PP_area_u_m', 'PP_bulk_mass', 'PP_bulk_mass_u_m', 'PP_ream_mass', 'PP_ream_mass_u_m', 'PP_grade', 'PP_abnormal_size', 'PP_paper_mass_basis', 'charge_item', 'pull_up_safety_stock_rule', 'pull_up_safety_stock_value', 'commodity_jurisdiction', 'eccn_usml_value', 'export_compliance_program', 'sched_b_num', 'hts_code', 'country', 'fcst_bom_supply_flag']
  , itemloc_mst  : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'whse', 'item', 'rank', 'loc', 'qty_on_hand', 'mrb_flag', 'loc_type', 'inv_acct', 'unit_cost', 'perm_flag', 'qty_rsvd', 'matl_cost', 'lbr_cost', 'fovhd_cost', 'vovhd_cost', 'out_cost', 'lbr_acct', 'fovhd_acct', 'vovhd_acct', 'out_acct', 'wc', 'inv_acct_unit1', 'inv_acct_unit2', 'inv_acct_unit3', 'inv_acct_unit4', 'lbr_acct_unit1', 'lbr_acct_unit2', 'lbr_acct_unit3', 'lbr_acct_unit4', 'fovhd_acct_unit1', 'fovhd_acct_unit2', 'fovhd_acct_unit3', 'fovhd_acct_unit4', 'vovhd_acct_unit1', 'vovhd_acct_unit2', 'vovhd_acct_unit3', 'vovhd_acct_unit4', 'out_acct_unit1', 'out_acct_unit2', 'out_acct_unit3', 'out_acct_unit4', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'NewRank', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'last_count_qty_on_hand', 'last_count_qty_rsvd', 'qty_contained', 'assigned_to_be_picked_qty', 'inv_in_proc_acct', 'inv_in_proc_acct_unit1', 'inv_in_proc_acct_unit2', 'inv_in_proc_acct_unit3', 'inv_in_proc_acct_unit4', 'lbr_in_proc_acct', 'lbr_in_proc_acct_unit1', 'lbr_in_proc_acct_unit2', 'lbr_in_proc_acct_unit3', 'lbr_in_proc_acct_unit4', 'fovhd_in_proc_acct', 'fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1', 'fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2', 'fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3', 'fovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4', 'vovhd_in_proc_acct', 'vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit1', 'vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit2', 'vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit3', 'vovhd_in_proc_acct_unit4', 'out_in_proc_acct', 'out_in_proc_acct_unit1', 'out_in_proc_acct_unit2', 'out_in_proc_acct_unit3', 'out_in_proc_acct_unit4', 'count_sequence']
  , job_mst      : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'type', 'job', 'suffix', 'job_date', 'cust_num', 'ord_type', 'ord_num', 'ord_line', 'ord_release', 'est_job', 'est_suf', 'item', 'qty_released', 'qty_complete', 'qty_scrapped', 'stat', 'lst_trx_date', 'root_job', 'root_suf', 'ref_job', 'ref_suf', 'ref_oper', 'ref_seq', 'low_level', 'effect_date', 'wip_acct', 'wip_total', 'wip_complete', 'wip_special', 'revision', 'picked', 'whse', 'jcb_acct', 'ps_num', 'wip_lbr_acct', 'wip_fovhd_acct', 'wip_vovhd_acct', 'wip_out_acct', 'wip_matl_total', 'wip_lbr_total', 'wip_fovhd_total', 'wip_vovhd_total', 'wip_out_total', 'wip_matl_comp', 'wip_lbr_comp', 'wip_fovhd_comp', 'wip_vovhd_comp', 'wip_out_comp', 'rollup_date', 'wip_acct_unit1', 'wip_acct_unit2', 'wip_acct_unit3', 'wip_acct_unit4', 'jcb_acct_unit1', 'jcb_acct_unit2', 'jcb_acct_unit3', 'jcb_acct_unit4', 'wip_lbr_acct_unit1', 'wip_lbr_acct_unit2', 'wip_lbr_acct_unit3', 'wip_lbr_acct_unit4', 'wip_fovhd_acct_unit1', 'wip_fovhd_acct_unit2', 'wip_fovhd_acct_unit3', 'wip_fovhd_acct_unit4', 'wip_vovhd_acct_unit1', 'wip_vovhd_acct_unit2', 'wip_vovhd_acct_unit3', 'wip_vovhd_acct_unit4', 'wip_out_acct_unit1', 'wip_out_acct_unit2', 'wip_out_acct_unit3', 'wip_out_acct_unit4', 'prod_mix', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'description', 'config_id', 'co_product_mix', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'scheduled', 'rcpt_rqmt', 'export_type', 'contains_tax_free_matl', 'midnight_of_job_sch_end_date', 'midnight_of_job_sch_compdate', 'rework', 'unlinked_xref', 'prospect_id', 'is_external', 'preassign_lots', 'preassign_serials', 'config_doc_id', 'MO_bom_alternate_id', 'MO_bom_alternate_description', 'MO_co_job', 'MO_product_cycle', 'MO_qty_per_cycle', 'MO_job_description']
  , jobmatl_mst  : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'job', 'suffix', 'oper_num', 'sequence', 'matl_type', 'item', 'matl_qty', 'units', 'cost', 'qty_issued', 'a_cost', 'ref_type', 'ref_num', 'ref_line_suf', 'ref_release', 'po_unit_cost', 'effect_date', 'obs_date', 'scrap_fact', 'qty_var', 'fixovhd_t', 'varovhd_t', 'feature', 'probable', 'opt_code', 'inc_price', 'description', 'pick_date', 'bom_seq', 'matl_qty_conv', 'u_m', 'inc_price_conv', 'cost_conv', 'backflush', 'bflush_loc', 'fmatlovhd', 'vmatlovhd', 'matl_cost', 'lbr_cost', 'fovhd_cost', 'vovhd_cost', 'out_cost', 'a_matl_cost', 'a_lbr_cost', 'a_fovhd_cost', 'a_vovhd_cost', 'a_out_cost', 'matl_cost_conv', 'lbr_cost_conv', 'fovhd_cost_conv', 'vovhd_cost_conv', 'out_cost_conv', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'alt_group', 'alt_group_rank', 'planned_alternate', 'new_sequence', 'manufacturer_id', 'manufacturer_item', 'PP_matl_is_paper', 'MO_formula_matl_weight_pct']
  , jobroute_mst : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'job', 'suffix', 'oper_num', 'wc', 'setup_hrs_t', 'setup_cost_t', 'complete', 'setup_hrs_v', 'wip_amt', 'qty_scrapped', 'qty_received', 'qty_moved', 'qty_complete', 'effect_date', 'obs_date', 'bflush_type', 'run_basis_lbr', 'run_basis_mch', 'fixovhd_t_lbr', 'fixovhd_t_mch', 'varovhd_t_lbr', 'varovhd_t_mch', 'run_hrs_t_lbr', 'run_hrs_t_mch', 'run_hrs_v_lbr', 'run_hrs_v_mch', 'run_cost_t_lbr', 'cntrl_point', 'setup_rate', 'efficiency', 'fovhd_rate_mch', 'vovhd_rate_mch', 'run_rate_lbr', 'varovhd_rate', 'fixovhd_rate', 'wip_matl_amt', 'wip_lbr_amt', 'wip_fovhd_amt', 'wip_vovhd_amt', 'wip_out_amt', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'yield', 'opm_consec_oper', 'MO_shared', 'MO_seconds_per_cycle', 'MO_formula_matl_weight', 'MO_formula_matl_weight_units']
  , location_mst : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'loc', 'description', 'loc_type', 'mrb_flag', 'wc', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow']
  , poitem_mst   : ['AUDIT_ID', 'AUDIT_TimeStamp', 'AUDIT_UID', 'AUDIT_RecType', 'AUDIT_TransId', 'site_ref', 'po_num', 'po_line', 'po_release', 'item', 'stat', 'qty_ordered', 'qty_received', 'qty_rejected', 'qty_voucher', 'qty_returned', 'item_cost', 'ref_type', 'ref_num', 'ref_line_suf', 'ref_release', 'due_date', 'rcvd_date', 'vend_item', 'root_job', 'root_suf', 'plan_cost', 'voucher_cost', 'non_inv_acct', 'drop_ship_no', 'drop_seq', 'ship_addr', 'promise_date', 'release_date', 'whse', 'item_type', 'cost_type', 'comm_code', 'trans_nat', 'process_ind', 'unit_weight', 'delterm', 'origin', 'cons_num', 'unit_mat_cost', 'unit_duty_cost', 'unit_freight_cost', 'unit_brokerage_cost', 'tax_code1', 'tax_code2', 'export_value', 'ec_code', 'transport', 'req_num', 'req_line', 'u_m', 'qty_ordered_conv', 'item_cost_conv', 'plan_cost_conv', 'unit_mat_cost_conv', 'unit_duty_cost_conv', 'unit_freight_cost_conv', 'unit_brokerage_cost_conv', 'non_inv_acct_unit1', 'non_inv_acct_unit2', 'non_inv_acct_unit3', 'non_inv_acct_unit4', 'lc_override', 'revision', 'drawing_nbr', 'po_vend_num', 'NoteExistsFlag', 'RecordDate', 'RowPointer', 'description', 'CreatedBy', 'UpdatedBy', 'CreateDate', 'InWorkflow', 'expedited', 'rcpt_rqmt', 'unit_insurance_cost', 'unit_insurance_cost_conv', 'unit_loc_frt_cost', 'unit_loc_frt_cost_conv', 'trans_nat_2', 'suppl_qty_conv_factor', 'unlinked_xref', 'due_date_day', 'preassign_lots', 'preassign_serials', 'ipr_id', 'ipr_seq', 'manufacturer_id', 'manufacturer_item', 'fa_num', 'fa_class', 'dept']
  }

const myForm = document.forms['my-form']; // to get form's child by their names

// set list of tables
Object.keys(data).forEach (name => myForm.tableSel.add( new Option(name,name)));

// check any input on form
myForm.oninput = ({target:frmElm}) =>
  {
  if (frmElm.name === 'tableSel') // or evt.target.name
    {
    myForm.columnSel.length         = 1;
    myForm.columnSel.selectedIndex  = 0;
    myForm.columnSel[0].textContent = 'Please Select a column'

    data[myForm.tableSel.value].forEach(val => myForm.columnSel.add( new Option(val,val)));
    }
  // show / hide myForm.lookupSel element
  myForm.lookupSel.closest('label').classList.toggle('noDisplay', myForm.columnSel.value === '');
  }
```

```css
label
  { 
  display     : block;
  font-size   : .8em;
  font-weight : bold;
  margin-top  : 1em;
  }
input, select
  { 
  display     : block;
  font-size   : 1em;
  font-weight :normal;
  }
.noDisplay { display : none; } /* use a class ! */
```

```html
<form action="pageToVisit" name="my-form">
  <label>Choose a table:
    <select name="tableSel" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Table</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Column to Filter:
    <select name="columnSel">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select a Table First</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label class="noDisplay">
    Lookup Value:
    <input type="text" name="lookupSel" value="">
  </label>
</form>
```